# authblk: Affiliation not shown in superscript with newtx

Tags: luatex, newtx, authblk

For some reason, the affiliation identifiers are shown as regular text when `authblk` is used with `newtx`. The problem doesn't occur when I do not use `newtx`.

I am using texlive 2022.

```tex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{Note}}
\author[1]{Author A}
\author[2]{Author A}
\affil[1]{Affil A}
\affil[2]{Affil B}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

%\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{Note}}
\author[1]{Author A}
\author[2]{Author A}
\affil[1]{Affil A}
\affil[2]{Affil B}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### Edit

The problem doesn't exist with `pdflatex`, but only with `lualatex`. The complete log can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKlXeeuZR82MdPPeOwdqZO2487yCE4rj/view?usp=share_link.

Comment: looks ok here. Show your complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have edited my question.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[defaultsups]{newtx}`.

Comment: That solves the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newtx package tries to use real scripts in footnote markers. But the `authblk` switches back to the normalfont and so it fails. Either load newtx with the `defaultsups` option, or redefine the `authblk` commands and move the normalfont outside of the textsuperscript:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{authblk}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{{\normalfont\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{{\normalfont\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{Note}}
\author[1]{Author A}
\author[2]{Author A}
\affil[1]{Affil A}
\affil[2]{Affil B}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]